# how generate emma in html report file from coverage.ec file

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, emma

I want to generate emma report in .html format from coverage.ec file.
I run below command

```
$ java emma report -r txt,html -in /Users/user.name/Desktop/coverage.ec
```

and it is processing like this

```
EMMA: processing input files ...
EMMA: 1 file(s) read and merged in 20 ms
EMMA: nothing to do: no metadata found in any of the data files
```

After processing,it is not generating any coverage.html report file.

Please provide any solution.